# Stack data alignment in windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce

I have built a test for a driver in Windows CE 6.0 and some tests fail because memory passed in is not properly aligned.

How can I control the alignment of auto variables on the stack (not inside structures)?

Keep in mind that I cannot change this test in any way except how I build it.

Comment: I have never encountered such a problem. Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error message, the problem is when an unsigned byte is declared on the stack, the address is not 4-byte aligned, and I need it to be.

The exe that is built is a conformance test and I cannot change the code.  When I build for windows the stack vars are 4-byte aligned, but when I build for CE they are not aligned

Comment: Edit your original question with info like this or use a COmment in the answer you're clarifying for.  Only provide an Answer if you are answering your actual question.

Comment: I lost the handle to the account I asked this question from

Answer (score 0):

Automatic variables are automatically aligned according to their natural alignment, unless you explicitly tell the compiler not to do so.  So, if you need an address with 4 byte alignment, declare a 4 byte variable, like a DWORD.